# Elasticsearch: Handling updates out of order

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I have the following document:

```
{
  "name": "Foo"
  "age": 0
}
```

We receive events that trigger updates to these fields:

```
Event 1
{
  "service_timestamp": "2019-09-15T09:00:01",
  "updated_name": "Bar"
}

Event 2
{
  "service_timestamp": "2019-09-15T09:00:02",
  "updated_name": "Foo"
}
```

`Event 2` was published by our service 1 second later than `Event 1`, so we would expect our document to first update the "name" property to "Bar", then back to "Foo". However, imagine that for whatever reason these events hit out of order (`Event 2` THEN `Event 1`). The final state of the document will be "Bar", which is not the desired behavior.

**We need to guarantee that we update our document in the order of the "service_timestamp" field on the event.**

One solution we came up with is to have an additional `last_updated_property` on each field like so:

```
{
  "name": {
    "value": "Foo",
    "last_updated_time": 1970-01-01T00:00:00
  }

  "age": {
    "value": 0,
    "last_updated_time": 1970-01-01T00:00:00
  }
}
```

We would then only update the property if the `service_timestamp` of the event occurs *after* the `last_updated_time` of the property in the document:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "if (ctx._source.name.last_updated_time < event.service_timestamp) { 
                 ctx._source.name.value = event.updated_name;
                 ctx._source.name.last_updated_time = event.service_timestamp;
               }"
  }
}
```

While this would work, it seems costly to perform a read, then a write on each update. Are there any other ways to guarantee events update in the correct order?

#### Edit 1: Some other things to consider

We cannot assume out-of-order events will occur in a small time window. Imagine the following: we attempt to update a customer's name, but this update fails, so we store the update event in some dead letter queue with the intention of refiring it later. We fix the bug that caused the update to fail, and refire all events in the dead letter queue. If no updates occurred that update the name field during the time we were fixing this bug, then the event in the dead letter queue should successfully update the property. However, if some events did update the name, the event in the dead letter queue should not update the property.

Comment: Every document you store in Elasticsearch has an associated version number. That version number is a positive number between 1 and 2 ^63-1 (inclusive). When you index a document for the very first time, it gets the version 1 and with every write-operation to this document, whether it is an index,update or delete, Elasticsearch will increment the version by 1, so you should look that up instead of the timestamp. Have a look at "Elasticsearch Versioning System".

Comment: @TunaMcFish How would I be able to use the version number? Create a new version with each update, but set some sort of "in-use" version to be whichever update timestamp is the most recent?

Comment: When you `GET` a document you get back a `_version` field in the response. Now what you would simply do is add that version number to your `POST` for instance, and what Elasticsearch has to do is to compare the two version numbers and if it's the same version then the update will go through successfully and you'll get `200 OK` otherwise (the version is not the same) elastic will not perform the operation and it would signal that back to you with `309 CONFLICT`.  Now if I understand your problem correctly I don't see why you would still have to use the custom "update timestamp" field at all.

Comment: Like if your service fired two update events against the same version of a given document then the first one will succeed but the second one is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: @TunaMcFish Ah that's an interesting idea. The only issue I see with that is what if I want to modify the name, then the age field in quick succession? In theory, the name update will increment the version, causing the age update to fail. However, I want both to succeed since these events do not cause any sort of conflict

Comment: In that case just don't send the version number in the "age update". Versioning is not enforced by default in Elasticsearch. In other words elastic won't check for the version number unless you explicitly send it in the request.

Comment: @TunaMcFish But it's possible for the age updates to be out of order as well. Essentially, I need some sort of property-level versioning

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I'm not aware of such a Versioning technique on that level, as much as I wouldn't personally prefer to send multiple update requests for each field in a single document (I would rather send one single request), I guess you have your reasons to do so, so if that is the case you could just stick with the versioning system as to make sure everything's working as expected and then catch those 309 conflicts and resolve them as per your business needs.

Answer (score 2):

Everything Mousa said is correct wrt "Internal" versioning, which is where you let Elasticsearch handle incrementing the version.

However, Elasticsearch also supports "External" versioning, where you can provide a version with each update that gets checked against the current doc's version. I believe this would solve your case of events indexing to ES "out of order", and would prevent those issues across any timeframe of events (whether 1 second or 1 week apart, as in you dead letter queue example).

To do this, you'd track the version of documents in your primary datastore (Elasticsearch should never be a primary datastore!), and attach it to indexing requests.

First you'd create your doc with any version number you want, let's start with 1:

```
POST localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/<doc id>?version=1&version_type=external -d
{
  "name": "Foo"
  "age": 0
}
```

Then the updates would also get assigned versions from your service and/or primary datastore

```
Event 1
POST localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/<doc id>?version=2&version_type=external -d
{
  "service_timestamp": "2019-09-15T09:00:01",
  "updated_name": "Bar"

}

Event 2
POST localhost:9200/my-index/my-type/<doc id>?version=3&version_type=external -d
{
  "service_timestamp": "2019-09-15T09:00:02",
  "updated_name": "Foo"
}
```

This ensures that even if the updates are applied out of order the most recent one wins. If Event 1 is applied after event 2, you'd get a `409` error code that represents a `VersionConflictEngineException`, and most importantly Event 1 would **NOT** override event 2.

Instead of incrementing a version int by 1 each time, you could choose to convert your timestamps to epoch millis and provide that as the version - similar to your idea of creating a `last_updated_property` field, but taking advantage of Elasticsearch's built in versioning. That way, the most recently timestamped update will always "win" and be applied last.

I **highly** recommend you read this short blog post on Elasticsearch versioning - it goes into way more detail than I did here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-versioning-support.

Happy searching!